Message: session not created from unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
On my Ubuntu server 22.04.4, I installed Python, Selenium, Chrome, Chromedriver and when I tried to run my script I got some errors.
We have the 126.0.6478.126 Chrome version and also the 126.0.6478.182 chromedriver version.
This is the python program:
from web_scraper import WebScraper
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

import os

filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0]

def scrape_func(driver):
    title = driver.title
    url = driver.current_url
    timestamp = datetime.now()
    elemento_h1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/h1')

    data = {
        'Title': [title],
        'URL': [url],
        'Timestamp': [timestamp],
        'h1': [elemento_h1]
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return df
    
scraper = WebScraper('https://es.investing.com/equities/', scrape_func)
df = scraper.scrape_site()
scraper.save_to_s3(df, filename)
scraper.close()


This is the WebScraper class:
class WebScraper:
    def __init__(self, url, scrape_func):
        chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        #Service=ChromeDriverManager()
        #chromeOptions.binary_location = 'usr/bin/google-chrome'
        driver_path = './chromedriver'
        chromeOptions.add_argument('--headless')
        chromeOptions.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        chromeOptions.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
        chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
        #service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, options=chromeOptions)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.base_url = url
        self.scrape_func = scrape_func

    def scrape_site(self):
        self.driver.get(self.base_url)
        sleep(5) 
        df = self.scrape_func(self.driver)
        sleep(5) 
        return df

This was the error log:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SessionNotCreatedException                Traceback (most recent call last)
File /workspaces/dwh-etls/src/main/docker_images/scrapping/main_test.py:26
     23     df = pd.DataFrame(data)
     24     return df
---> 26 scraper = WebScraper('https://es.investing.com/equities/', scrape_func)
     27 df = scraper.scrape_site()
     28 scraper.save_to_s3(df, filename)

File /workspaces/dwh-etls/src/main/docker_images/scrapping/web_scraper.py:19, in WebScraper.__init__(self, url, scrape_func)
     17 chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
     18 #service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
---> 19 self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, options=chromeOptions)
     20 self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
     21 self.driver.maximize_window()

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py:71, in WebDriver.__init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options)
     68 self.service.start()
     70 try:
---> 71     RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
     72         self,
     73         command_executor=ChromeRemoteConnection(
     74             remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url),
     75         desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
     76 except Exception:
     77     self.quit()

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:156, in WebDriver.__init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    153 if browser_profile is not None:
    154     warnings.warn("Please use FirefoxOptions to set browser profile",
    155                   DeprecationWarning)
--> 156 self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
    157 self._switch_to = SwitchTo(self)
    158 self._mobile = Mobile(self)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:251, in WebDriver.start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    248 w3c_caps = _make_w3c_caps(capabilities)
    249 parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps,
    250               "desiredCapabilities": capabilities}
--> 251 response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    252 if 'sessionId' not in response:
    253     response = response['value']

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:320, in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    318 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    319 if response:
--> 320     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    321     response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    322         response.get('value', None))
    323     return response

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:242, in ErrorHandler.check_response(self, response)
    240         alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary


I do not have any ideas on how to fix this. I need help.
